# How add ArrayList in input Boolean Parameters

Tags: jenkins, groovy

i want to create dynamic booleanParameters:

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'master' }
    stages {
        stage('load stage'){
         steps{
            script{
            def listParam =[]
            listParam.add(booleanParam(name: 'a', defaultValue:false ))
            listParam.add(booleanParam(name: 'b', defaultValue:false ))
            listParam.add(booleanParam(name: 'c', defaultValue:false ))
              def userId = input  message: 'Please select a or b or c ',
              ok : 'RUN',id :'userId',
              parameters(listParam)
            echo "userId ${userId}"
            }
          }
        } 
    }
}
```

and console log return this :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected named arguments but got [{message=Please select a or b or c, ok=RUN, id=userId},
> @parameters(=[@booleanParam(name=a,defaultValue=false),
> @booleanParam(name=b,defaultValue=false), @booleanParam(name=c,defaultValue=false)])]
> at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.parseArgs(DSL.java:588)
> at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.parseArgs(DSL.java:526)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [ref-doc](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/) you want to pass your `listParam` as a part of map with key `parameters`:

```
def listParam = [ booleanParam(name: 'a', defaultValue:false ),
                  booleanParam(name: 'b', defaultValue:false ),
                  booleanParam(name: 'c', defaultValue:false ), ]

def userId = input  message: 'Please select a or b or c ',
                    ok : 'RUN',id :'userId',
                    parameters:listParam
```

Comment: if a nad b and c are generated dynamically . now , how can i used boolean parameters a or b or c . i use syntax --> userid[0] but it`s incorrect

Comment: ask another question, add relevant info to it

Comment: if you wanna get  any item of list you can use this code           for (item in  userId) {
              echo " ${item.getKey()} ${item.getValue()}"
           }

Answer (score 0):

Create an list of booleanParam object and add the elements that you wish
Example:

def listParam = [booleanParam(name: "All")]

```
    for (product in globalVariables.productsList){
        listParam.add(booleanParam(name: "$product"))
    }
```

def USER_INPUT = input message: 'User Input', ok: 'Start', parameters:listParam